# Want to extend jQuery to select by name attribute more elegantly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

I find this selector format cumbersome if I need to use it often:

```
$('[name="someElementName"]').val()
```

I thought about extending jQuery so that I can use a format like this:

```
$('@someElementName').val()
```

I understand that jQuery is just following the convention of CSS and that I am breaking convention.

Regarding the choice of "@", I just picked a special character that seemed unused for selectors and not likely to create a conflict. If anyone has a better suggestion I'm open to suggestions.

I don't have the option to not use the name attribute as part of the selector.

I was thinking about using regular expression like this:

```
selectorString.replace(/\@([\d\w\s\-]*)/g, '[name="$1"]')
```

From here I am stuck as how to extend jQuery to utilize that regex in such a way that I can use code like "$('@someElementName').val();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
(function($) {
    $.named = function(name, context) {
        context = context || document;
        return $(context.getElementsByName(name));
    }
})(jQuery);
```

usage:

```
$.named('foo').val();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/n6nEW/

Comment: @Alnitak IMHO, it's not as elegant as the solution I desired, but its an improvement over my original problem. I have built on your code so we can have chaining: your code plus `$.fn.named = function(arg){ return $(this).filter('[name="' + arg + '"]'); };` See http://jsfiddle.net/CE2Mm/ - I have no idea if this code represents good practice.

Comment: @DG if you're going to go that route, use a function in `.filter` instead, e.g. `.filter(function(idx) { return this.name === arg })`

Comment: @DG it's also more efficient to ask the DOM directly for the elements you want, than to have jQuery extra too many, and them throw away the results for the unwanted elements.